# Angular: Build form from matchList to save results

Tags: forms, angular

I´d like to build a reactive form with matches that have no result yet.

> Team A - Team B    [input Goals A] : [input Goals B]
>
> Team C - Team D    [input Goals C] : [input Goals D]

and so on. When a user then edits both fields in a row, the full result should be send to my database. How can I achieve that?

My current status:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.formGroup = new FormGroup({});

  if (this.showResultInput && this.articles) {
    this.articles.forEach((article: IArticle) => {
      this.formGroup.addControl(article.$key  + '[homeGoals]', new FormControl());
      this.formGroup.addControl(article.$key  + '[guestGoals]', new FormControl());
  });

  this.formGroup.valueChanges.debounceTime(500).subscribe((resultArrayList: any) => {
    console.log(resultArrayList);
  });
}
```

and my template:

```
  <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <div *ngFor="let match of matches; let i = index;">
      {{match.title}}</a>
      <input type="number" [formControlName]="match.$key + '[homeGoals]'">
      <input type="number" [formControlName]="match.$key + '[guestGoals]'">
    </div
  </form>
```